# AppDelegate code only runs on Background

Tags: ios, background, appdelegate, ibeacon, foreground

I'm developing an iOS app that uses CoreLocation in order to manage iBeacons. I have Beacon detection in both the AppDelegate and ViewController, but I want the AppDelegate detection to only work when the app is in background state. I send analytics to a server when the user enters or leaves a region, so if both (AppDelegate and ViewController) detections work when the app is in Foreground, the app will send doubled analytics.

Any solutions to make a code (the server call to send analytics) not to run when the app is in Foreground?

Comment: I would suggest you only have one class (another singleton or referenced as a property of your app delegate) to handle your location detection. You can use the `applicationState` property of the UIApplication object to determine whether you are in the background or foreground.

Answer (score 1):

In AppDelegate start your beacon detection in the applicationDidEnterBackground: method and stop beacon detection in the applicationWillEnterForeground: method.

Answer (score 1):

Simply implement methods in your AppDelegate to track if you are in the foreground, and stop sending analytics from your AppDelegate if so.  See below:

```
  - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
  {
      _sendAnalytics = YES;
  }

  - (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
  {
       _sendAnalytics = NO;
  }
```

Then add an if statement before sending analytics from the AppDelegate to check the value of _sendAnalytics.

Centralizing this logic as @paulw11 suggests in his comment would probably make the code cleaner, but if you do need to send analytics in two places, the above will solve your problem.